# How can I set the priority of a DispatcherTimer?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, dispatchertimer

I am creating an app for Windows Phone 7 using Silverlight in C#.

I have found many references to the DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority) overload, but I cannot set this in my code (e.g. timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority) tells me "DispatcherPriority does not exist in the current context").

I thought DispatcherTimer is overloaded with DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority) but I cannot see any reference to this constructor when I use it in my code. I would like to try setting the priority to "normal" or "send" but I cannot seem to implement any DispatcherTimer with a priority. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

The constructor that takes the Dispatcher Priority only exists in the full .NET framework - that is for WPF.  The DispatcherTimer in Silverlight/WP7 doesn't support priorty.

Compare the documentation for DispatcherTimer in .[NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and for [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: That is what I suspected. Thanks for the answer!!